# How to use Email and .NET to conduct RESTful interactions

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, email

I'm refactoring an email-based order entry system where a WordPress-based order form generates an email that my .NET/IIS assembly parses and imports to my db. Currently, it's just one-way and works 95% of the time.

5% of the time, the form submission had invalid data and my boss's secretary (Sally) gets an email alerting her to the fact that a given transaction needs her attention. She fires up her browser and navigates to the site's admin page where she works her magic and updates are committed.

What Sally wants instead, is to be able to simply hit reply; edit a couple lines in the email body; and update the db without having to use her browser.

I'm looking for examples where this pattern (email-based updates) is explored as an alternative to conventional form's based interactions.

thx

Comment: Danger! Database interaction through email can expose delicate data to malicious users.

Comment: What sort of protocol would you expect to use? You can easily create a service that monitors a POP3, IMAP, Exchange, etc. email account, retrieves new messages, and parses the subject and body for updates. For example you can use `Pop3Client`. However, if you want clearer examples, we'll need to know a little more about your setup. I don't think ASP.NET, MVC, or REST are relevant here.

Comment: You guys make an excellent one-two punch. ;) And yes, I guess this really does boil down to nothing fancier than C# parsing string data. I'm accessing the inbox with a .net component - I working with the same database that is serving the back-end tier of an MVC web-app. I want to perform the same actions via the email channel that conventional MVC views currently handle. In a sense I'm trying to use email bodies as replacements to Views and looking for validation. don't think security is an issue cuz Sally uses SSL-based GMail interactions and we already trust her with the company's jewels.